# Is there ever a time when computing the limit of Riemann sums is the best way to compute a definite integral?

Tags: calculus, soft-question

Is there ever a time when computing the limit of Riemann sums is the best way to compute a definite integral?

The use of Riemann sums is a great way to approximate the area under the curve, and the area under the curve is exactly equal to the limit as the number of rectangles goes to infinity (or as the maximum width of the rectangle goes to zero).

I feel like a common stumbling block in calculus instruction is how it is typical to introduce Riemann sums, do some approximations, express a given area as the limit as the number of rectangles goes to infinity, and then start computing integrals. Students get the idea that evaluating definite integrals is about computing the limit of Riemann sums rather than using antiderivatives and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

So I was wondering... Is there ever a time when a closed form antiderivative is not available, but the limit of Riemann sums is computable without too strenuous of effort? I don't think I've ever seen an example of this kind before.

Comment: Well, this is essentially how Archimedes computed his integrals, and he did not know of antiderivatives...

Comment: The definite integral is the result of evaluating a limit which represents the converging value of the ever more precise determination of the area. Because of being a limit is never reached, despite our best efforts. Even when the antiderivative s help us calculate it, we still found the limit. Even the area of a rectangle is the result of evaluating a limit.

Comment: There are very extremely many functions without closed form antiderivatives ...

Answer (score 6):

This isn't quite what you're asking for, because there is no limit taken.  But sometimes we don't even know the function.  I used to work for a power company and we bought electricity off the grid.  This electricity is not measured like the electricity to your house (in kilowatthours.)  Instead, once per hour the "load" was measured.  The amount of electricity is the integral of the load.  All we know about the load function is its value every hour on the hour.  The Trapezoid rule was used to estimate the area and that's what we paid for the power we used.

So the point is: You have to use Riemann sums (or something similar) when you don't know what the actual function is.